# Embedding local html file as a Microsoft Browser Object in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("https://www.bing.com")
End Sub
```

I'm trying to embed a local html file as a web object in power point.  For the above link the code is working fine, but when I replace it with a local file, the nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Local files don't use `http://` they use `file:///`

so something like:

```
file:///c:/test/test.html
```

Take notice of the 3 slashes after `file:` (they cannot be backslashes like file paths usually are.)

Comment: It works fine for me and everyone else. Did you try it in a browser first? Maybe there is something wrong with your file.

Comment: I'll try again. The HTML file is opening perfectly in the browser.

Comment: Maybe try it without the `(` and `)` and make sure you are using forward slashes and not backslashes like a filename normally would have.

Comment: My HTML file has a lot of JS, which is being called in the body. Basically I created a network map in R, which I'm trying to embed in powerpoint. When I call the html file in powerpoint, I get the notification "To help protect your security, your computer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer."

Comment: Ok, well that is a completely different question. You may want to ask that question instead.

Comment: @Will so, the html document *is* loading then, and this answers your question. There's quite a difference between loading a static HTML document from a local file, and then allowing some arbitrary JavaScript to run in there.

Comment: You are probably going to have problems tho, as that is a security feature that is controlled by the user, so each user would have to grant permissions on their end for anything like that to work.

Comment: @braX Thanks a lot. I'll ask this question specifically.